# Expected behavior of Jenkin's Node Label Plugin - Not running on all nodes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-agent

I am trying to use the plugin Node label plugin, adding a *Label* parameter and selecting the *Run on all nodes matching label* in a pipeline job.
But this only runs on  one of the nodes even though nodes are discover-able by *Show nodes* in the build page.

I have also tried using the *All Nodes for Label Factory* option the same plugin provides, but this fails when I want more than one label in the jobs, as described here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-59431  (including latest comment)

After many hours spent on google I have come to believe that when I use *Label* with *run in all* all of the nodes will run concurrently, the only difference with other examples I've seen online is the fact that they are not pipeline jobs, so concurrent jobs is a selectable option, compared to the *Do not allow concurrent builds* option in pipeline (which is not selected)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone had this problem, I decided to answer this question.

I made the trigger job a pipeline, where I build the downstream job with 2 parameters inside a loop through all the nodes with label:

```
def nodeArray = nodesByLabel label:"${params.labeled}", offline: false
for(item in nodeArray) {
    build job:"DownstreamJob", parameters:[
            [$class: 'LabelParameterValue', name: 'node', label: "${item}"],
            string(name:"nodeToRunIn", value:"${item}")
        ], propagate: false, wait:false
}
```

And in the DownstreamJob I start with:

```
node (params.nodeToRunIn) {
```

May not be the nicest solution, as that would have been to have the plugin work as expected, but this is currently working.